# How to overcome the error Unbound Local Variable?

Tags: python

I am making a project in which I have to define `t` before entering into the function `label` but it is giving me an error mentioned below.

Below is the sample code not project code which is giving the same error as in project. Anyone can guide me?

```
global t
t=0
def label():
    for i in range(3):
        t+=1
    print(t)
x=label()
```

Comment: Define ```global t``` inside the function

Comment: At global context `t` knows it's global. The function thinks it's local; you have to declare `t` as global inside the function instead.

Comment: Reconsider the use of global variables unless really necessary. Maybe you can provide it as a function parameter and return it afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Write the `global` keyword inside the function -

```
t=0
def label():
    global t
    for i in range(3):
        t+=1
    print(t)
x=label()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify to the function that `t` is your `global t`:

```
global t
t=0
def label():
    global t
    for i in range(3):
        t+=1
    print(t)
x=label()
```

Comment: I have specified t as global t inside the function as you can see in the code. Can you tell any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `global t` inside the function

```
t=0
def label():
    global t
    for i in range(3):
        t+=1
    print(t)
x=label()
```

Comment: global t is already inside the function. I am not getting your point.

Comment: @SafiUllah, this is the finalanswer